# React Native : How to maintain multiple state of a component

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-router

I am a newbie in React Native. I am using **redux** architecture for my react native app for **Android**.

I want to maintain the state of a page.

[image]
Suppose for example I have 2 pages as you can see in the picture.

**Navigating forward** from page A to page B, **state of B changes from initial state to apple**. Then to page A again and clicking on MANGO will navigate to page B where **state of page B will change from apple to mango**.

Now while **navigating back**, the state of B always be mango(i.e latest state of that page). Where I want to maintain the state of page B as apple or mango. I want to maintain the multiple instance of page B in the navigation stack.

**Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`react-router-redux`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux). It let's you sync your router with redux state.

#### Example

Install `react-router-redux`. Then, in your store setup, add this piece of configuration.

```
...
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'
...

...
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)
...
```

This will keep the navigation state in sync with your redux state.

Comment: okay thanks. I will give it a try. One more thing, Why on page B the state goes from initial state to Apple and then apple to Mango. I want state of page B to change **always from initial to any other state**. How to achieve this?

Comment: Create an action that resets your state to initialState when this condition applies.

Comment: react-router-redux is for reactjs...Can I use it for react native? or is there any other library in react native to achieve my requirement.